# Refreshing an ASP.Net GridView when changes are made to DetailsView

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, refresh, detailsview

We have an ASP.Net / VB.Net code-behind web form. On this form is a GridView and a DetailsView.

When there is a change in the details view we would like the changes to be reflected in the GridView.

This code is being used to populate the GridView:

```
Private Sub Teachers_Init(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Init

    ' Load the data from the database into the GridView.
    '---------------------------------------------------
    GridViewSummary.DataSource = theTableAdapter.GetDataAllTeachers
    GridViewSummary.DataBind()
End Sub
```

This coding is being used to reflect the changes in the GridView after a change to the details are made in the DetailsView:

```
Private Sub DetailsView_ItemUpdated(sender As Object, e As DetailsViewUpdatedEventArgs) Handles DetailsView.ItemUpdated

    ' Refresh the data so current values are displayed.
    '--------------------------------------------------
    GridViewSummary.DataSource = theTableAdapter.GetDataAllTeachers
    GridViewSummary.DataBind()
End Sub
```

Is there a way to not need the use of:

```
    GridViewSummary.DataSource = theTableAdapter.GetDataAllTeachers
```

in the above coding? I know it's just 1 line of code but would like to eliminate it if it's not needed.

Comment: Unless you are using a scriptmanager with an update panel, no there is no way to get rid of that code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In the markup we do have the GridView and the Details view inside an UpdatePanel.